# Start systemd in docker-compose and call another function

Tags: docker, process, docker-compose, systemd, suse

I am trying to start `systemd` in a SuSE container using `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd` and then call another function, for example `echo "Hi"` in docker-compose or docker. This is what `/bin/bash -c "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd && echo 'Hi'"` would theoretically do, but with the big issue that `systemd` isn't starting up since the bash process has the `PID1` and `systemd` has the `PID2` leading to the error message that `systemd` can not be started from the user land.

I was partially successful with Yelp's `dumb-init` (since it accepts arguments to run after itself) but would prefer a complete systemd. Additionally it would be pretty good to have a simple oneliner instead of having to call a script (if that would be a solution, since that would probably also lead to the bash-process having `PID1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why are starting systemd at all. Which feature of `systemd` do you want to use?

If just want to run something after systemd as started, then writing a simple systemd `.service` file is the way to go.

See `man systemd.service` and `man systemd.unit` for more on systemd's config files.

Comment: Well I have some dependencies on systemd that I have to respect. However, I agree that service-files could be a way to go, even though that would be quite cumbersome as I want do run a different command from docker than from docker-compose. I guess I could add an environment variable and have the script run by my service-file decide which command to run. I would prefer a more straightforward solution though.